Why does env -S with quoted strings in the shebang line work fine in Ubuntu but not in macOS?
I have the following script in an executable file test-shebang.mjs and I wanted to use zx to run my script but have my ~/.zshrc be sourced before that:
#!/usr/bin/env -S zsh -c 'source ~/.zshrc; zx --install $@' --

console.log("work pls")

./test-shebang.mjs works fine in Ubuntu:
❯ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy

❯ zsh --version
zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)

But when I copy over the same script in macOS, I get this error:
❯ ./test-shebang.mjs
zsh:1: unmatched '

❯ zsh --version
zsh 5.9 (x86_64-apple-darwin23.0)

❯ sw_vers
ProductName:        macOS
ProductVersion:     14.4
BuildVersion:       23E214

Why does this happen?
I tried with bash as well but running into errors there as well. FWIW, I'm doing this roundabout way of doing things because I've installed zx via pnpm which itself is installed via brew and I would prefer not to set PATH which would just make the script longer.

Does the Mac version of env support the non-standard -S option?

According to the man pages for env on MacOS and on Ubuntu 20.04, the -S option works differently in the two operating systems.  This is probably because much of the MacOS userland commands came from BSD sources and the Linux userland commands came from GNU.

@SottoVoce I thought the same at first but this bit in the doc made me think otherwise: https://pub.microbin.eu/upload/snail-bison-ape — maybe I misread this or is macOS pre-FreeBSD 6.0 but for some reason, the man page doesn't make it clear?

Shebang lines are parsed slightly differently on different Unix kernels. On Linux and on modern BSD, the command is followed by a single argument (or none), which can contain spaces. On macOS, the command is followed by zero or more arguments separated by spaces.
So on Linux, when you run ./test-shebang.mjs with the argument foo, this is what happens:

The kernel runs /usr/bin/env with the arguments -S zsh -c 'source ~/.zshrc; zx --install $@' -- (note that all of that is the first argument), ./test-shebang.mjs, foo.
env runs zsh with the arguments -c, source ~/.zshrc; zx --install $@, --, ./test-shebang.mjs, foo.
Zsh runs the script source ~/.zshrc; zx --install $@ with the script name -- and the two positional parameters ./test-shebang.mjs, foo.
After .zshrc returns, zsh runs zx with the arguments --install, ./test-shebang.mjs, foo.

On macOS the first step is different (inherited from old versions of FreeBSD), which results in unintended data that is detected in the third step:

The kernel runs /usr/bin/env with the arguments -S, zsh, -c, 'source, ~/.zshrc;, zx, --install, $@', --, ./test-shebang.mjs, foo.
env runs zsh with the arguments -c, 'source, ~/.zshrc;, zx, --install, $@', --, ./test-shebang.mjs, foo.
Zsh runs the script 'source with the script name ~/.zshrc; and the positional parameters zx, --install, $@', --, ./test-shebang.mjs, foo.
Zsh complains that 'source is not a syntactically correct script.

Unfortunately, env -S on Linux and FreeBSD compensates for their shebang parsing weirdness, but macOS mixes FreeBSD's env utility with a different shebang parsing, so env -S doesn't work as intended (or in any particularly useful way) on macOS.
The portable solution for complex shebangs is to write a polyglot with a #!/bin/sh shebang, and a second line that contains shell code written specially to be a no-op in whatever language the script is in. For example, here's an sh+JavaScript polyglot  (assuming a JS variant that treats shebang lines as comments) that does the same thing as your shebang line.
#!/bin/sh
eval : '; exec zsh -c "source ~/.zshrc; zx --install \$@" -- "$0" "$@"';
console.log("Javascript code starts here");


In sh, the second line is the built-in command eval with the two arguments : and ; exec zsh -c "source ~/.zshrc; zx --install \$@" -- "$0" "$@". This causes sh to run : ; exec zsh -c "source ~/.zshrc; zx --install \$@" -- "$0" "$@". : is a no-op command. The exec built-in causes sh to replace itself by zsh, so sh stops parsing the file after the second line.
In JavaScript, the second line is a string literal (which has no effect), with the label eval (which is useless but harmless).


Note that what you've put in the script is really weird and unlikely to be helpful. .zshrc is intended for interactive customizations and is likely to cause weird effects when used in a non-interactive shell. .zshrc should not set environment variables since these variables would not be available in non-terminal programs and would be reset if you run a nested zsh; you should set environment variables in .zprofile instead.

Thanks for the detailed answer, I'll need to peruse this carefully once again but I guess you've hit the nail on the head w.r.t difference in behavior which is what I thought. You mentioned "kernel runs /usr/bin/env" which is not something I fully realized which explains the difference even better. But I read this bit from the macOS man page for env and thought the behavior is consistent now: Maybe I misread something but there is this section in man env in macOS: https://pub.microbin.eu/upload/snail-bison-ape which made me think this'd work fine—was I wrong or is the man page out of date?

I almost feel the correct solution is to clobber all env variants with one that has an env -S that works no matter what. Did it get "env" "-S" "argument argument"; split it. Did it get "env" "-S" "argument" "argument" nothing to split. Did it get "env" "-S argument argument" split it. This does however mean the interpreter name can't have a space in it. I have said universal env lying around but it doesn't have gnu long options and won't run anywhere but linux as env itself must be ported. Too bad.

@runofthemillgeek The man page on macOS is a copy of the FreeBSD one. Apple missed that they should have edited that section, which is correct for FreeBSD but not for macOS.

@Joshua Yes, it would have been better if macOS had modified their env to make env -S work in most cases. Or if they'd followed the shebang parsing change in FreeBSD.

Thanks for confirming that. What a mess Apple has created for themselves and the developers who stick to their systems.

I've reported this via Feedback Assistant although I doubt it helps given all my past legitimate bug reports are still open :/

Some good news: looks like macOS Sequoia 15.0 (Dev Preview, 24A5264n) fixed the incorrect man page usage section. Here's what it reads now: https://gist.github.com/runofthemillgeek/3b7a84a0aa5f323d3fcc54fde051b9ae
Basically says this won't work in macOS shell scripts (:
